# PDF reader performance on Citrix or TS RDP

Tags: performance, terminal-server, citrix, pdf

I'm considering to use different PDF reader in Citrix Environment. Which company has the best software product that performs better in Terminals and Adobe?

I'm considering Foxit, Nitro and Docudesk. The latency between US server and EU clients is 150ms so that is one of the main reasons why I would like to have something more efficient in place.

Comment: Give them a try and use a stopwatch.

Comment: This is getting closed - and don't feel bad about it. It's just that it attracts so many spammers. Use google instead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We stopped using Adobe long time ago since it became a huge load of different things the use storage, use CPU and users do not need those features. Lately foxit version 4.x is used on all the terminal servers, it is super fast, small and free.

Comment: We did the same. You might consider a little program we found called Sumatra. I found it's even more lightweight than Foxit. Good luck!